# Saving icons to Document directiry and load for all iphone sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics

I need to save icons to phone document folder instead of storing in my project folder. I will have `icon.png,icon@2x.png,icon@3x.png`. When I load from document folder I will just use @"icon.png", so will `iOS` can pick up correct sizes according to phones?

Comment: Better to use XCAsset.

Comment: why are you not using assets ?

Comment: It will even if you dont use XCAsset, but recommended to use it

Comment: For some reasons, I cannot store those icons in  assets because I need to download those icons dynamically. Those icons will not be same always.

Comment: Though icons has to be same. icon.png file or AppIcon in XCAsset use for application main icon which comes on iOS devices. If you are planning to download from somewhere and use it dynamically, that would not work.

Answer (score 1):

No if your icons will be in document directory then `iOS` could not differentiate between `1x,2x or 3x`. So you should use `assets`. And if you have fixed icons!

If you are getting icons at runtime then you should download only one icon which have higher resolution so that it will show good in every device. Because you can't put it to assets.

Comment: so may i know which is the best way to load icons if i have to save in document directory? My app is like users need to enter specific code first, according to that code I need to ask API for all the icons.

Comment: Perfect judgement, +1 Bro.

Comment: then you not required to download all size of image !! you should download only 3x (i mean largest) image so that it will show good in every resolution!

Comment: Can someone please explain why this answer is upvoted and accepted? How can images that are downloaded at runtime be put in assets or the project folder?

Comment: Not possible @rmaddy ! Thats why i have said that you he should download high resolution image only instead of three images in comment!

Comment: Your answer states *"And if you want store icons in documents directory then also first you need to put it to assets or project folder"*. This makes no sense when talking about images that will be downloaded at runtime. And the actual answer shouldn't be in comments.

Comment: Actually when i have written answer at that time it is not cleared that images are dowloaded at runtime. Questioner have latter said that in comment!

Comment: You still have that incorrect statement in your answer.

Comment: @rmaddy : which one? And if you found something wrong in answer then you should edit it!!

Comment: *"Which one?"* The one I quoted in my 2nd comment.

Answer (score -2):

better to use XCAsset.

**Please refer steps given in below**

[image]

- Goto XCAsset
- Add AppIcon if not available there
- Select required device property from right panel
- Add related image by drag and drop

Comment: thanks for the answers but I cannot save in asset folder due to some reasons.

Comment: Could you give your answer as a step-by-step answer, rather than an animated gif? That'd make it much easier for people to use.